# What spells are best to use when using the BARCH strategy?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When farming in Clash of Clans, I like to use the BARCH strategy (Barbarians and Archers) to farm resources. However, I was wondering if there was a way to further supplement my army with spells. What are the best spells to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lightning spells to take out buildings that deal splash damage to your troops like mortars rather than on single target buildings like cannons and archer towers. If you can, try to use your troops to lure the enemy's clan castle onto the building which you will destroy. Thus, making your raid much more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend healing and rage spells, healing spells can help your troops deal with splash damage from mortars and rage spells can help your troops wipe out tough buildings quickly.

Comment: It would be better to take out the splash dmg dealers than to heal your troops for only 20 secs of the 2 minute raids.

Comment: @Neffer_23: Cheaper too. Rage costs more to brew than lightning.

Comment: @Neffer_23 Good Point

Comment: Healing is waste for barbarian and archers. They will destroy in seconds in splash damage.

Answer (score 1):

Boost your barbarian king and take few heal spell.. heal king with spell... I am sure archer behind king make loot of dark elixir at TH8.

Answer (score 0):

I would use lightning spells to take out defences like mortars that cause splash damage and not single targeted defences such as cannons.

Answer (score -2):

Use lightning spells to take out buildings that deal splash damage to your troops like mortars rather than on single target buildings like cannons and archer towers. If you can, try to use your troops to lure the enemy's clan castle onto the building which you will destroy. Thus, making your raid much more efficient.

Comment: This does not answer my question. In fact, I don't understand what you are trying to explain. Please edit this.

Comment: please disregard the edit... just read my answer instead

Comment: thats copied from above...